# Convert json dictionary column to key-value pair rows (Redshift+Postgresql)

Tags: json, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have the following schema in redshift (an id column and a json dictionary as a string)

```
id data
1 {'1': 'true', '2':'false'}
2 {'1': 'false', '3':'true'}
```

and I would like to transform it to:

```
id key value
1 '1' 'true'
1 '2' 'false'
2 '1' 'false'
2 '3' 'true'
```

What would be an appropriate postgresql query for this? I have tried using JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT but then I need to union together all the individual keys and I am dealing with hundreds of keys.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
select id,json_object_keys(t.data) as key,data->json_object_keys(t.data) as value from t;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/781fd/10

Comment: Unfortunately redshift uses postgresql 8.1 so the json function from later postgresql versions don't work. The above gives me the following error "[42883] ERROR: function json_object_keys("unknown") does not exist"